# Видеострим через WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, видео, ffmpeg

Необходимо воспроизводить неоконченный видеофайл средствами 
videojs/videotag/canvas. Стрим должен воспроизводиться на всех мобильных устройствах.

Есть видеопоток iptv записывающийся в реальном времени на диск.

Я не могу его воспроизвести в html5 плеерах, пока он не будет завершен. На ум приходит только одно решение. Считывать некоторое кол-во байт из файла, отправлять через вебсокеты клиенту, и воспроизводить.

Знания в js почти нулевые, могу только принимать данные от сервера(c#), ну а дальше не знаю как проиграть плеером.
Буду рад любой инфе о том как скормить поток байт плееру

upd1:

задуманное получается только если писать поток в webm средствами vlс, тогда большинство плееров проигрывают видео файл на лету! НО декодинг потока занимает 20-30% CPU на i7 kabylake и т.к я планирую вести больше десяти трансляций одновременно, этот вариант отпадает

upd2:

декодинг в OGG занимает крайне мало ресурсов и подходит, НО почему-то  отстает звук(2-3сек) и я уже все испробовал, но не смог пофиксить это. 
Задержки со звуком есть только при рестриме ogg по http, например по rtsp задержек нет

Comment: https://github.com/cargomedia/ws-video вот похожее решение, но на media source, который не проигрывается на ios, а так же не стримит ничего кроме видео из примера целиком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решает jsmpeg. [Link](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg)

Начальный видеопоток прогоняется через ffmpeg на собственный сервер от jsmpeg, далее по вебсокету на canvas.

Comment: Но у меня изображение и звук жутко лагают. Не знаю что с этим делать